# How to trigger specific action after event on all opened tabs in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Imagine that we have a web application in which a user can log in.

After authorization, the user has access to his list of projects. When the page with projects is loaded, the client sends a request to the server and receives this list. When a new project is added, a second request is made to the server, and the list of projects is updated.

At this stage, everything is clear.

Now imagine that the user has opened a list of projects in several tabs in the browser at once. After changing the list on one open tab, a certain "trigger" should be triggered, which will force the remaining open components to perform certain actions.

More specifically.

**We have the same link opened three times in different tabs: "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3".**

**The user has created a new project on "Tab 1" and I need "Tab 2" and "Tab 3" to request new data from the server and update the list.**

Please tell me how best to implement this. I tried using Vuex and it worked while there was no pagination in the application. Pagination does not allow storing all objects in one list, because different pages can be opened on different open tabs. Any ideas would be helpful. It may still be worth using a Vuex, but in a different way, or the solution lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

what about socket.io ? have you read about it ?
i think you could achive your desire performance with it

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution could be: use `POST` request in nuxt proxy server or in your backend, like `axios.post('/data', payload)` and connect the websockets, you can use [pusher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pusher) for that. The final logic is: user add some data => post to server => server emits the websockets event => vuex listen to the event and the data will be reactive in all tabs.